# Count simultan requests in a PHP script

Tags: php

I'm searching for a way to count the current number of request to a certain file.

```
//start of script
$count = get_number_of_current_requests();
set_number_of_current_requests($count+1);

...

//end of script
$count = get_number_of_current_requests();
set_number_of_current_requests($count-1);
```

I've tried using a file to store the process and also a MySQL database entry but some tests failed and the value is not `0` after all processes are finished.

Is there "best way" to this kind of check?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what else might be wrong with your code, but you have a small race condition at each update: Between the time you fetch the count and the time you store the new value, another thread might have done the same. You'll be better off delegating concurrency to MySQL, by asking for increment or decrement like this:

```
UPDATE stats SET connections to connections + 1 [ WHERE ... ]
```

The connection count never makes it to the PHP process. You only need to retrieve it when you want to display it.

Comment: Thanks, is this "bullet proof" or should I expect some problems?

Comment: It's not bulletproof. For one, the count is only decremented if the PHP process terminates normally. It's just the correct way to implement your approach.